# Calculating the parameters of the logistic function: $L(t)=\frac{a}{1+\exp(b-ct)}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

$$L(t)=\frac{a}{1+\exp(b-ct)}$$

Choose the parameters $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ to get that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \space L(t)=50, \space L(0)=5, \space L(10)=25 $

There is a hint that:

$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a}{1+\exp(b-ct)} = \frac{a}{1+\exp(-\infty)}=a=50
$$

I can't get that step (why has became $(b-ct)$ to $-\infty$ in the dominator and unfortunately I even don't know how to continue the calculation. Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

First note that

$$
L(t) = \frac{a}{1 + e^{b - ct}} = \frac{a}{1 + e^ be^{-ct}} \tag{1}
$$

now, if $c>0$ then

$$
\lim_{t\to \infty} e^{-ct} = 0 \tag{2}
$$

and then

$$
\lim_{t\to \infty} L(t) = \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{a}{1 + e^b e^{-ct}} \stackrel{(2)}{=}  a = 50 \tag{3}
$$

So now you have the other condition

$$
5 = L(0) \stackrel{(1), (3)}{=} \frac{50}{1 + e^b \cancelto{1}{e^0}} = \frac{50}{1 + e^b} ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ 1 + e^b = 10 ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ e^b = 9 \tag{4}
$$

So far we have

$$
L(t) = \frac{50}{1 + 9 e^{-ct}} \tag{5}
$$

I'm going to leave the last step (find the value of $c$) to you